# Do Windows GDI APIs return error code in GetLastError?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, getlasterror

I know it's an old technology, but I'm curious, do Windows GDI APIs return error codes in GetLastError()? I have several instances when DeleteObject and DeleteDC fail but error code is returned as 0.

Comment: The answer to such a question is found in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most GDI functions do not use `GetLastError()`.  GDI functions that are capable of reporting specific errors will return error codes directly in their return values.  Not all GDI functions can report specific errors, though.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance in the PSDK:

DeleteObject and DeleteDC:

> Return Values - If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero.
>
> Windows NT/2000/XP: To get extended error information, call
>   GetLastError.

The PSDK/MSDN is your friend.

Comment: How about providing a link for what you're quoting? I don't see any mentioning of GetLastError in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539(v=vs.85).aspx